# How to quantitatively measure how simplified a mathematical expression is

Tags: math, symbolic-math

I am looking for a simple method to assign a number to a mathematical expression, say between 0 and 1, that conveys how *simplified* that expression is (being 1 as fully simplified). For example:

- `eval('x+1')` should return 1.
- `eval('1+x+1+x+x-5')` should returns some value less than 1, because it is far from being *simple* (i.e., it can be further simplified).

The parameter of `eval()` could be either a string or an abstract syntax tree (AST).

A simple idea that occurred to me was to count the number of operators (?)

---

**EDIT:** Let *simplified* be equivalent to how close a system is to the solution of a problem. E.g., given an algebra problem (i.e. limit, derivative, integral, etc), it should assign a number to tell how close it is to the solution.

The closest metaphor I can come up with it how a maths professor would look at an incomplete problem and mentally assess it in order to tell how close the student is to the solution. Like in a math exam, were the student didn't finished a problem worth 20 points, but the professor assigns 8 out of 20. Why would he come up with 8/20, and can we program such thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "simplified"? In what system? According to which rules? There's nothing as an *absolute* measurement of "simplicity" in a mathematical expression. Which one do you consider simpler `3(x + 5)` or `3x + 15`? Both have the same number of operands; if you represent those terms in a tree, you have exactly the same number of nodes and edges.

Comment: You could simplify it yourself by some algorithm, and then do a measure of difference between them, or count the number of steps needed to simplify it. That will also help you define exactly what you mean by "simpler".

Comment: @HugoSFerreira the method could return the same value for those inputs. Ok, I'm gonna edit my question.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser I have made an algorithm that simplifies math expressions, but I want it to estimate how close it is to the solution without doing the steps.

Comment: Maybe you can check for the computation time between your first expression and the simplified one, but it's not really accurate.

Comment: [Ask Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how+complex+is+x%2B1%2B1%2Bx%2Bx%2B1%3F&x=0&y=0), comparing the DOM nodes from "input" with "result".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to break a stack-overflow rule and post this as an answer instead of a comment, because not only I'm pretty sure the answer is **you can't** (at least, not the way you imagine), but also because I believe it can be educational up to a certain degree.

Let's assume that a criteria of simplicity can be established (akin to a [normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form_(abstract_rewriting))). It seems to me that you are very close to trying to solve an analogous to *[entscheidungsproblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem)* or the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). I doubt that in a complex rule system required for typical algebra, you can find a method that gives **a correct and definitive answer** to the number of steps of a series of term reductions (*ipso facto* an arbitrary-length computation) **without actually performing it**. Such answer would *imply* knowing in advance if such computation could terminate, and so contradict the fact that automatic theorem proving is, for any sufficiently powerful logic capable of representing arithmetic, an [undecidable problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving#Decidability_of_the_problem).

In the given example, the teacher is actually either performing that computation mentally (going step by step, applying his own sequence of rules), or gives an *estimation* based on his experience. But, there's **no generic algorithm that guarantees his sequence of steps are the simplest possible**, nor that his resulting expression is the simplest one (except for trivial expressions), and hence any quantification of "distance" to a solution is meaningless.

Wouldn't all this be true, your problem would be simple: you know the number of steps, you know how many steps you've taken so far, you divide the latter by the former ;-)

Now, returning to the criteria of simplicity, I also advice you to [take a look](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/news/Thiele.pdf) on [Hilbert's 24th problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_24th_problem), that specifically looked for a *"Criteria of simplicity, or proof of the greatest simplicity of certain proofs."*, and the slightly related [proof compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_compression). If you are philosophically inclined to further understand these subjects, I would suggest reading the classic [Gödel, Escher, Bach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach).

---

**Further notes:** To understand why, consider a well-known mathematical artefact called the [Mandelbrot fractal set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set). Each pixel color is calculated by determining if the solution to the equation `z(n+1) = z(n)^2 + c` for any specific `c` is bounded, that is, *"a complex number `c` is part of the Mandelbrot set if, when starting with `z(0) = 0` and applying the iteration repeatedly, the absolute value of `z(n)` remains bounded however large `n` gets."* Despite the equation being extremely simple (you know, square a number and sum a constant), there's absolutely no way to know if it will remain bounded or not **without actually performing an infinite number of iterations or until a cycle is found** (disregarding complex heuristics). In this sense, every fractal out there is a **rough approximation** that typically usages **an escape time algorithm** as an heuristic to provide an **educated guess**  whether the solution will be bounded or not.

Comment: Your answer just blowed my mind, it shows me that I have a LOT to learn.

Comment: I just realized that in the example of the teacher, most of the time he previously has solved the problem, then he knows that the computation will terminate, and more or less the number of steps required. The hard thing is to estimate based on experience. And what if we dont need to find the definitive number of steps, just an aproximation with certain error? It still isn't possible? Or it still wouldn't be helpful?

Comment: The process of solving a problem of prove of trigonometric identities can be seen as a search algorithm in a tree. When I have to decide between applying two identities, I will use my experience or intuition to decide which one is close to the solution (or which one is more human-like). I want to build something like that for my [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system).

Comment: @gab06: how do you plan to give intuition to a computer? :-) besides the search-space being intractable for anything more than relatively simple arithmetic, you'll still have no guarantee that the end result is the simplest form available. It's very good that you're enthusiastic with this subject, but my advice is to read the resources I've pointed out, understand the concept of *undecidability*, and enrol in a Theory of Computation course, like this free one on Automata (https://www.coursera.org/course/automata) :-)

Comment: By the way, your search-space does not constitute a *tree*, but a *graph*, since you can easily apply a sequence of operations over an expression that eventually come back to a previous form. Now imagine this huge graph (e.g. roads and cities), where you're trying to find a particular town, but which you have **no clue** if it is north or south of you. Now imagine I ask you the minimum number of intersections between where you are and this city. How would you answer this *without actually tracing* (at least partially) every possible path?

Comment: Nice answer. Close to what I would have given, but would add a section on [rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting) and point out [confluence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_(abstract_rewriting))